# Internationalization in Syncfusion Ej2 with WebPack

Tags: angular, webpack, syncfusion

I'm trying to use the internationalization features of Syncfusion EJ2 in Angular-Cli with WebPack, which is problematic because all the documentation uses SystemJs.

In particular I'm trying to use this [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/4uA2rb0Q2FrLLK6V4sne)

```
import { L10n, loadCldr, setCulture, setCurrencyCode } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import * as currencies from './currencies.json';
import * as cagregorian from './ca-gregorian.json';
import * as numbers from './numbers.json';
import * as timeZoneNames from './timeZoneNames.json';
import * as numberingSystems from './numberingSystems.json';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { data } from './datasource';

loadCldr(currencies, cagregorian, numbers, timeZoneNames, numberingSystems);

setCulture('de-DE');
setCurrencyCode('EUR');
```

I tried but could not make it to work, I'm stuck on this error:

> ```
>  Cannot find module './numberingSystems.json'
> ```

Which changes should I make to the sample?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to import the json files in the typescript, we need to include the json type in the wildcard card module declaration( https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations ). Use the below declaration code in the typings.d.ts  file to resolve the compilation issue.

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

*Note: You can also use the cldr json files by installing the npm package cldr-data. This package contains all cultures json files.*

Comment: Now works as expected, thanks. I installed the clrd-data package, I'm importing the files this way

import * as numbers from '../../node_modules/cldr-data/main/es-AR/numbers.json';

There is a "better" way?

Comment: The JSON files can also imported be using require as mentioned in the below snippet.

loadCldr(require('../../node_modules/cldr-data/main/de/numbers.json'));

For using the require in the anguar-cli app we need to declare the require in typings.d.ts file as below snippet

declare var require: any;